# People who has access the particular node in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to know that user name who has access to The particular node in firebase android
Firebase Node
https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0KxO.png
let Suppose username who has access to HIJ node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although your question is not clear, seems that what you're looking for is FireBase Realtime Database Rules, where you can define rules to govern access control over your DB. Check out the documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/

Comment: i want to know user name who has access particular node